# Search non-direct messages in slack

Tags: search, slack

In slack, can I search messages in public/private channels only? I would like to exclude direct messages to me from the search because I know I have already read them. I am interested in finding information about a topic I may have missed in channels.

Answer (score 2):

One can use:

```
-is:dm SEARCH_QUERY
```

E.g. to list the non-direct messages that I sent in Slack:

```
-is:dm from:me
```

`-` is the negative search operand.